# go to the next index of an array using onclick in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, onclick

I apologize in advance if I'm vague or my code is difficult to understand, I'm still learning this stuff. I'm trying to display information that is stored within an array. I want to display this information when a button is clicked and when it is clicked again, the next index in the array displays its information..

I need help setting up a function that advances to the next index of the array. Thanks!

(function(){

```
var students =[                       //array of information
    {name:'john', 
    address:{
        address:'821 Imaginary St',
        city:'Chicago',
        state:'Il'},
    gpa:[4.0,3.5,3.8]},

    {name:'jim',
    address:{
        address:'127 fake Rd',
        city:'Orlando',
        state:'Fl'},
        gpa:[2.5,3.3,3.6]}];

    var redBut = document.querySelector('.buttonred');
redBut.onclick = getInfo;
var count = 0;

    function getInfo(){

      var stn = students[0];
      if(count<3){
         count++;

        document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = 'Name: ' + stn.name;          //this is what is to be displayed when the button is clicked
        document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = 'Address: ' + stn.address.address + " " + stn.address.city + ", " + stn.address.state;
        document.getElementById('gpa').innerHTML = 'GPA: ' + stn.gpa[0] +", " + stn.gpa[1] + ", " + stn.gpa[2];
        document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = 'Date: ' + d.toLocaleDateString();
        document.getElementById('gpaavg').innerHTML = 'Average GPA: ' + gpas;
```

}

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:    `var stn = students[count];`

And not:    `var stn = students[0];`

(DOH!)